# Ajax posting notes with specific id

Tags: php, jquery

I have a index.php-file that hold some client data, each client data has a unique id.
A "create-a-note"-form (using ajax) sends a note to mysql table and instant post the note to index.php.
The problem is that i can't get the client_id over to the processing file so all records is being displayed on all clients:

index.php

```
echo "
<div class='note' id='typenote".$clients_id."'> 
<form>*the form*</form>
</div>
<div id="notes"></div>
";
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showNote(){
        $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"process.php",
          data:"action=shownotes",
          success:function(data){
                $("#notes").hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
          }
     });
 }

 showNote();

 $("#button").click(function(){
    var user=$("#user").val();
    var note=$("#note").val();
    var client_id=$("#client_id").val();

        $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"process.php",
          data:"user="+user+"&note="+note+"&client_id="+client_id+"&action=addnote",
          success:function(data){
            showNote();
          }
        });
 });
});
```

Process.php

```
    include("connect.php");

    $action=$_POST["action"];

    if($action=="shownotes"){
      $show=mysql_query("Select * from sys_notes order by note_id desc");
    etc...

}
  }
  else if($action=="addnote"){
etc...
```

HERE IS THE PROBLEM...
How do i get the value of $client_id

```
Select * from sys_notes WHERE client_id=$client_is order by note_id desc
```

in the process.php-file so correct notes is populated in my showNote() scripts id (#notes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1 - Never use mysql_ functions (nobody should) use mysqli_ if you must or better yet take a look at PDO

2 - Use $_SESSION global to hold things like user and userID (so they can't temper with it and change/display other users' data)

3 - for your problem I see that you're sending the client_id already so why not just grab it from there?

Hope this helps

Comment: 3 - true, but that only when i´m POST the data. First action ($action=="show notes") is displaying the posted notes so far, when the form is submitted the client_id is sent... is there a way to pull the id to $action=="show notes"?

Comment: You could use the hidden field option and ttransfer it accross your pages OR better yet use a session to hold the data you need between requests

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put a query string to `data`? `data` wants an object array or you have to put the query string to the `url`.

```
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"process.php",
      data:{user: user, note: note, client_id: client_id, action: "addnote"},
      success:function(data){
        showNote();
      }
    });
```

or (method2)

```
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"process.php?user="+user+"&note="+note+"&client_id="+client_id+"&action=addnote",
      success:function(data){
        showNote();
      }
    });
```

then you can access client_id with `$_POST['client_id']` or (method2) with `$_GET['client_id']`

Comment: 1st method is working for posting! Thanks, but that is only when i´m POST the data. First action ($action=="show notes") is displaying the posted notes so far, when the form is submitted the client_id is sent... is there a way to pull the client_id to $action=="show notes"?

Answer (score 0):

The client ID should not be sent with the form as that can be manipulated by the client. That means one client could add notes for another client by changing a number in the html.

I would assume that your client is logged-in and that the ID is stored in a session so you would just access it in your php file like (just an example):

```
$_SESSION['client']['id'];
```